# mediumtext type for mysql migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I know that the maximum size of medium text is 16,777,215 bytes (16 mb)

I use the following rails migration

```
def change
    change_column :solutions, :result, :text, :limit => 16.megabytes - 1
end
```

But I don't need 16mb to be allocation for this results column. I just need 2mb

So will the following work?

```
def change
  change_column :solutions, :result, :text, :limit => 2.megabytes
end
```

or will it still allocate 16mb?

Comment: Creating a new migration to change limit to 2mb should work. Check `db/schema.rb` after applying the migration to confirm that the `solutions` table definition does define it with 2mb limit.

Comment: Why didn't you just try?

Comment: How to check if its actually assigning 16 mb or 2mb. I mean the question really is when you specify a limit for text, does it take that as the limit or the next upper limit.

For example when I specify limit=> 2mb will mysql take it as 16mb since the next upper limit is 16mb